# Django query set filter over relationship with concat

Tags: django, django-orm

I would like to filter Users based on their concat(first_name, last_name) which are accessible over UserProfile.

```
if user.profile.first_name + ' ' +  user.profile.last_name LIKE query
```

All I have is User.objects.all()

I tried some stuff with extra(), ComplexQuery,annotation() but none of them was working...

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Value, Func, F, CharField

User.objects.annotate(full_name=Func(F('first_name'), Value(' '), F('last_name'), function='CONCAT', output_field=CharField())).filter(full_name__icontains='Dusan Plavak')
```

Update #1:

```
User.objects.annotate(full_name=Func(F('profile__first_name'), Value(' '), F('profile__last_name'), function='CONCAT', output_field=CharField())).filter(full_name__icontains='Dusan Plavak')
```

Comment: See Update #1. You can access a related model field the same way you normally would.